# Estimate causal effect with lots of missing values

Tags: regression, experiment-design, missing-data, causality

This is a generic question. Suppose you run an experiment with units randomized between a treatment and a control group.

Imagine the response rate is very low in each group, say, below 10% and with a significant difference in participation between the treatments, which you may interpret as *causal* difference.

However, you are not mainly interested in differences in participation. You rather want to assess the treatment effect on how experimental units performed a certain task.

The problem is that, while you have for each participant a measure of performance (e.g., a score) for most of the population you only have a missing value.

Using the intention-to-treat difference on the score conditional on participation would, therefore, fail to distinguish between differences induced by the participation effect and a potential, more direct, effect on performance.

Is there a design or a regression technique that would allow to distinguish between these two effects?